# Раскрывающиеся(выпадающие) меню

Tags: android

Мне нужно сделать так что-бы при нажатии на кнопку у меня открывалось(раскрывалось) содержимое.
Допустим у меня есть кнопка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне нужно чтобы я на нее кликнул и она какбы раскрыло свое содержимое в низ. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похожая штука есть в приложении в ВК, есть новость и вней есть заглавная часть и при нажатии на нее вниз выезжает содержимое. Нужно что-то похожее.
Как это вообще называется и как это сделать?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/243363/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Довольно сложно понять по картинке, но тем не менее есть два варианта решения данной задачи: вручную создать данный эффект или использовать библиотеку. Для первого варианта рассмотрим пример. Создадим разметку:

```
<!-- activity_info layout file -->
<!-- Clickable title -->
<TextView   android:id="@+id/help_title_gest"
            style="@style/title_help"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="toggle_contents"/>

<!--content to hide/show -->
<TextView   android:id="@+id/txt_help_gest"
            style="@style/txt_help"
            android:text="@string/txt_content"/>
```

дальше в активности:

```
// inside Activity
 TextView txt_help_gest;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    txt_help_gest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_help_gest);
    // hide until its title is clicked
    txt_help_gest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}



public void toggle_contents(View v){
      txt_help_gest.setVisibility( txt_help_gest.isShown()
                          ? View.GONE
                          : View.VISIBLE );
}
```

для того чтобы все показывалось/скрывалось красиво сделаем анимацию `res/anim/slide_down.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fillAfter="true">

 <scale
 android:duration="200"
 android:fromXScale="1.0"
 android:fromYScale="0.0"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
 android:toXScale="1.0"
 android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

В другом классе, который используется для сервисных методов (не сервис), либо в активности добавляем метод для анимирования:

```
public static void slide_down(Context ctx, View v){

  Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.slide_down);
  if(a != null){
     a.reset();
     if(v != null){
      v.clearAnimation();
      v.startAnimation(a);
     }
  }
}
```

и дальше используем этот метод в самой активности:

```
public void toggle_contents(View v){

  if(txt_help_gest.isShown()){
    Fx.slide_up(this, txt_help_gest);
    txt_help_gest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
  else{
    txt_help_gest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Fx.slide_down(this, txt_help_gest);
  }
}
```

Вот первоисточник. Теперь по поводу библиотек. Есть довольно много разнообразных библиотек которые реализуют данное поведение. Могу предложить [такой вариант](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout). И [такой](https://androidhiro.com/source/android/example/expandable-layout/5356) туториал.

Comment: У меня получилось сделать вручную, только я не понял с анимацией. Что за другой класс, который используется для сервисных методов (не сервис). Его нужно как-то добавить в мой Activity? Или он просто должен существовать в проекте? И если его нужно добавить то как это сделать?

Comment: просто сервисный класс, может это я конечно его так называю)) паттерн называется синглтоном, вот есть статья по данному вопросу - https://habr.com/ru/post/27108/, сделайте такой же класс, чтобы можно было получить доступ к его методам отовсюду, это и будет сервисный класс

Comment: Я решил сделать через вторую библиотеку, только одного не пойму как в одной Activity сделать несколько таких ExpandableLayout

Comment: @Karpuha, это делается через разметку а не через класс :)